# does a visa extension have to have a health surcharge

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, health-insurance, paperwork, costs

I married my husband in June 2013 and came to the UK in September 2013 with a spouse visa. I am extending it in March and believe that I now have to pay a £500 surcharge.

Is this right even though I am working and pay national insurance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would be correct. Immigration Health Surcharge is required for any extension applications . You will not have to pay for this at the time you apply for your indefinite leave to remain. The system, in our view, is quite unfair and this is one of the most common questions we are asked when someone is contributing through taxes and NI.

Comment: Can you provide links to the relevant documentation?